# ZF2 annotationbuilder - select

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using the annotationbuilder to create a form from my annotations. But for some reason, if I add the @ORM line, the result is always an input field. If I remove the line, it is a dropdown but the selected value is not saved to the column...

```
  /** 
   * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
   * @Annotation\Required({"required":"false" })
   * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
   * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Einschränkung:", "value_options" : {"none":"keine Einschränkung","width":"Breite","height":"Höhe","both":"beides"}})
   * @ORM\Column(name="restriction")
   */
  private $restriction;
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh good god... turns out my doctrineORMmodule was outdated... this was apparently A BUG. 
Updating my composer.json like this

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master"
}
```

helped. Oh lord.